# Change camera's volume layer mask through code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using HDRP scene with HD Camera [LINK](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.2/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.CameraSettings.Culling.html).

I am trying to change the "volume layer mask" of this HD camera through code, but I am not able to get the right property. How can I alter the layer mask?

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition;

public class CameraLayerMask: MonoBehaviour {
    public HDCamera cam;

  void Start () {
       cam.volumeLayerMask = 1 << 0; //Does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `CameraSettings.Volumes.layerMask`?

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error ```'CameraSettings' does not contain a definition for 'Volumes' and no accessible extension method 'Volumes' accepting a first argument of type 'CameraSettings' could be found.```

Comment: No [`CameraSettings.Volumes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.2/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition.CameraSettings.Volumes.html) is a struct and it has a field/property `layerMask`. I thinking you would use `var settings = CameraSettings.From(cam);` and then `settings.volumes.layerMask = xxx;`

Comment: @derHugo Thanks!. I got another way to do this. I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways was to reference `HDAdditionalCameraData` since this was the property of camera in HDRP.

```
public HDAdditionalCameraData cam;
 
private void Start()
{
    cam.volumeLayerMask = 1 << 0;
}
```